# Can`t find the parent of a control which is in another page of a different project from source code

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

Hy,
Can someone tell me how can i find the page parent of an element in Silverlight 4. The element is in a page of a Project2 (is a userControl), and i want to find that page in the codeSource of the ControlElement. The code which i use now is this (this code is in control):

```
Project1.MainPage pageM = Application.Current.RootVisual as Project1.MainPage;
Page page = pageM.ContentFrame.Content as Page;
TabControl tabControl = page.FindName("tabControl") as TabControl;
```

But the problem is that i can-t add a reference to Project1 from Project2, because i have a reference to Project2. I need to find the parent because i want to add something in the tabControl from that page.

Here is how i use the control in Project1:

```
<usrctrl:Menu x:Name="Menu" VerticalAlignment="Top"HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,1,0,0">
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do?  Its not good to allow one project to have such intimate knowledge of the inner workings of another project.

Comment: I know, but i have to somehow add a element to that tabControl. The ideea is that i have a menu and when i click on a item from that menu i add a tabItem to a tabControl. Also i have to add element to the page grid, because it is a drop down menu generated from an xml and i don`t know how to write the code in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No... Stop... Don't... Go back... Danger ahead...

Please find a better way. Try commanding, MVVM & Prism event-handling. Anything but directly linking otherwise unrelated parts of your application together.

Heck even shared objects that both pages can see (data store?) would be an improvement (although also not recommended for serious development).